# warning in broker log about mixing offset commit types

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We had processors that commit the offset through the producer to achieve exactly-once delivery.

Recently I noticed that all offsets are even numbers (0,2,4,6,8) and that we have the following warning in the broker log.

```
[2019-01-24 03:06:24,473] WARN [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] group: xxxx-group with leader: 1e9856a9-bce1-4a28-9774-0117382a9751-4d9411d1-36fb-4332-af9b-beb65aedfed1 has received offset commits from consumers as well as transactional producers. Mixing both types of offset commits will generally result in surprises and should be avoided. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
```

Is there something wrong with how we are implementing exactly-once? will this really result in surprises?

Answer (score 1):

I guessing you are committing a transaction for every single record.

When committing (or aborting), a [control batch](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#controlbatch) is written to the partition and that takes an offset. This control record is invisible to clients but is used by brokers to delimitate transactions and find their final state.

Basically your records take the even offsets and for each one there's a commit control batch that takes the next offset.

Now regarding the warning in the logs:

You get this if there is a transactional producer and a consumer both committing offsets for the same group. You should ensure that only the transactional producer commits offsets so they are part of your transactions and records are processed once.